# PHP - Filtering by MySQL field value

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a table with some rows that contain 3 fields (category, title, image). At first I created a foreach loop that returned some html with the information from each of the rows. However, now I actually want to create a scenario where I can "filter" my loop by category.

What I mean to say is that I want to create a function that will only generate the html for rows that have a particular value for their category field. I want to be able to apply this function to all the different values for category.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why not filter it directly in your query? so you won't need any filters in your php code? all you have just to do is to display an html for the rows.

Comment: Is filtering using mysql okay?

Comment: yeah, you could have just something like this in your `where` clause, `WHERE category <> NULL`

Comment: As the other comments have suggested and I've used in my answer, a `WHERE` statement is one of the basic functions of MySQL that lets you filter your queries. Can you put up the code where you are querying mysql? Then I can show you how to modify it to match the query below..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MySql query solution:**
Use a `Where` Statement in your query, and keep your PHP the same.
e.g.

```
Select * From table Where `category`="Filter Value";
```

Let me know if that works for you, or if you're constrained to only using PHP to filter the category..

Comment: I wanted to do it PHP simply because I didn't know how easy of a solution it was to do in the mysql query.

Comment: MySQL is for querying. lol It's whole purpose is retrieving data.

Answer (score 1):

Either use the `WHERE` clause as asifrc suggested.

Or do something like this

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if($row['category'] == 'category1') {
      // do some stuff example
      $html_output .= '<p style="font-weight:bold">Important category: ' . $row['title'] . '</p>';
    } else if($row['category'] == 'category2') {
      // do other stuff
      $html_output .= '<p>Not important category: ' . $row['title'] . '</p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea, that's how I had it in PHP, but I was wondering if there was something less convoluted (I've got a lot of categories)

Comment: Does your handling of categories have to be unique for each category? Are there groups of categories? i.e. if there are 5 categories of categories then we can split them up using a switch. Or if the handling depends on some aspect of the category, that might be a clue. Any more info?